# MS Access 2010, control in data insertion

Tags: ms-access-2010

It's just the first time for me in this site so I hope to be precise as required!

I'm building an MS Access DB for billing and in particular I'd like to control 1 field in tables as it follows:

```
TABLE 1: bill, client .... other fields
TABLE 2: bill, client.... other fields
TABLE1 and TABLE2 are linked on "bill" with a join 1-to-many
```

First of all, i create manually a record in table 1, giving "bill" and "client"; then i create in table 2 a record in which - when i digit "bill" - the automatic control reads from table 1 "client" and provide to insert it automatically in table 2.

So I don't have to take care of it *(and of course I avoid errors in inserting wrong client)*.

I currently have a check by a query, but I prefer to avoid the problem during the online insertion.

I hope I have given a precise context of my problem.

Thanks so much!

Comment: So **bill** in `TABLE2` is a FK to the **bill** in the `TABLE1`, which is a PK? If so, why is your setup not a Main Form & Sub form? Which makes data entry very simple, without the use of excessive code.

Comment: Wow! I'll try, it sounds so simply. Thanks